# How to check if 3 fields are unique in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table without a defined Primary Key.
I suspect that 3 fields combined together are the actual key for this table.
In order to test this assumption first I need to check that this 3 fields are unique as a tuple.

I thought of doing something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(field_A, field_B, field_C) as pk
FROM My_table;
```

Now I want to search if this new field is repeated.
I know that I need to somehow group by and use having count(*)>1 but I can't get the proper syntax.

```
SELECT *
FROM My_table
GROUP BY CONCAT(field_A, field_B, field_C)
HAVING ? > 1
```

It feels like it's almost finished but I can't find the proper syntax to make it actually work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT count(*) cnt, field_A, field_B, field_C
FROM my_table
GROUP BY field_A, field_B, field_C
HAVING cnt > 1
```